# Rotate div continously but using only -180deg to 180deg with css transitions (Compass)

Tags: javascript, css, animation, rotation, css-transitions

I want to rotate a div from -180deg to 180deg without the div rotating back to 0 in between. Instead of taking the fastet way it is currently rotating all the way from -180 to 0 and only then to 180.

I read somewhere that CSS animations will never do that, but that I could use multiples of 180 or -180 to keep it rotating continuously. This is in my case not really feasible, because I use data related to the device orientation which is between 0 and 360.
(I am coding a little compass)

Is there a javascript library that handles such CSS animations?
Or is there a way to disable css transition in the very moment the position switches from minus to plus?

Thank you all for your input on this.

cheers

Comment: `Instead of taking the fastet way` --> what is the fastest way?

Comment: Is your current implementation using a transition or an animation?

Comment: @TemaniAfif
Instead of rotating like: -180, -179, 178 .... -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, ... 178, 179, 180°
(In this case it makes the slowest way: making a full rotation to land at the exact same point)
I want it to take the fastest way: (just stay at its position... or if we switch from -179 to 170, it should just rotate 11° instead of rotating (179° + 170°).

Comment: @MrLister CSS transition: transform: rotate()